# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification gradle issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting the issue All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification when I am trying to sync my gradle file. Can any one please tell me the way by which I can solve my problem. I have already gone through this solution [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification).  but unfortunately it is not working in my case. Below is my gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.application"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Is there no one who can help me on this? I am still in search of the solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
```

You have a dependency with the **support libraries v24.**

In general you can use this command to check your **dependencies tree.**

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```